# .htaccess doesn't work properly

Tags: .htaccess

i have .htaccess file which includes below code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^imagefactory/(.*)$ imagefactory/index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

i want .htaccess file which fulfill below requirements.
if
1) url/admin then go to the admin folder and choose it's .htaccess file
2) url/imagefactory then go to the imagefactory folder and choose it's file called index.php
3) url/ then it choose root directory's index.php file

Comment: Do you have full control over the Apache server? If yes, don't use .htaccess but a vhost and `<Location>` statements.

Comment: Just fyi if the user goes to url/ then it will default to index.[php, html, etc] if you are using apache (im not sure about other web servers).

as for the other ones, you may have to do a redirect because what your doing there means that both will be valid iirc; So I mean: url/admin and url/this/is/my/admin/folder will both be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^imagefactory/(.*)$ imagefactory/index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/.$ - [PT]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place the last rule 1 position up. This rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]` will match anything, and the [L] attribute there means not other rules will be evaluated when it matches. If you reorder it like below it should work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^imagefactory/(.*)$ imagefactory/index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess file is read in sequence.  The RewriteCond are only meant for one rule.

Therefore all you need is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^imagefactory/(.*)$ imagefactory/index.php?q=$1 [QSA, L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/admin/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA, L]
```

The second block is a catch all so that if its not from directory admin, use the default root index.php.